# Getting an error while bringing up spring boot application using Communda

Tags: spring-boot, camunda, camunda-modeler

I got the below error while bringing up Spring Boot application with Camunda encrypted. Any property I need to set?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.CamundaBpmWebappAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'properties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'camunda.bpm-org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.property.CamundaBpmProperties': 
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.property.CamundaBpmProperties]: 
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/camunda/bpm/dmn/engine/impl/spi/el/DmnScriptEngineResolver

at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$102/1473205473.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: what do you mean by "camunda encrypted"?

Comment: it means, the camunda is running within the spring boot application.

Comment: ah ... embedded